# Convert this CURL Command to Javascript fetch()

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have a problem, I'm trying to access an API via javascript fetch().

In their documentation, they only have the curl guide

```
curl https://test.com/form/{form_id}/data \
-u apikey:'some-key'
```

Can you guys help me convert it to javascript fetch?

I tested the code below but the browser console says error 401 now I don't think I did put the apikey on the right location.

```
    fetch(https://test.com/form/371489/data', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
           apikey : 'some-ley',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      })
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what is failing there is the type of header you are sending in fetch.

The -u option in curl translates to the "authorization" header in fetch. So it would be something like this.

```
fetch(https://test.com/form/371489/data', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'authorization' : 'Basic apikey:some-key',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  })
```

Although probably you would need to base64 encode the apikey:some-key portion before sending it.

Comment: Thanks, brother, I'll check this out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

fetch("https://test.com/form/{form_id}/data", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: "apikey ABCDEFGHIJK.."
  }
})

Comment: Ah forgot BASIC to auth, -u is auth single header

Answer (score 0):

Try these awesome online [cURL converters](https://curlconverter.com/javascript/)!
Here is the output when you paste the cURL command and select the Javascript target:

```js
fetch('https://test.com/form/371489/data', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('apikey:some-key')
    }
});
```